# Improve Django application logs to only display custom log from Logging settings

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to improve the logging of my Django application to have it in a standardized way for querying it with Loki and for each log that I create, 3 log entries are recorded. For example, any request (sucess or failed) to this endpoint below will generate three log entries.

- `views.py`

```py
class ModelViewSet(models.ModelViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # do something
            logger.info(f"{request.path} {request.method} 200: user {request.user.id} - success!")
            return Response(serializer.data)

        except Exception as exc:
            logger.warning(f"{request.path} {request.method} {exc.status_code}: user {request.user.id} - {exc.detail}")
            return Response(exc.detail, status=exc.status_code)
```

- `settings.py`

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'timestamp': {
            'format': '{asctime} {levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'timestamp'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

- Output in console

```bash
2022-06-02 10:26:09,714 WARNING /api/v1/<path/ GET 403: user 71 - You do not have permission to perform this action.
2022-06-02 10:26:09,814 WARNING Forbidden: /api/v1/<path/
2022-06-02 10:26:09,815 WARNING "GET /api/v1/<path/ HTTP/1.1" 403 12495
```

Any suggestion on how to optimize and have only one entry, preferably my custom logging entry and get rid of the other two? This will also help reduce drastically the size of the logs stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress messages from the Django package itself, you can just set the level to `CRITICAL` rather than `INFO` in the configuration. I can't tell which package your customized log message is from, but presumably it's not under the `django` package - in which case `WARNING` or higher messages should still come through. If you change the format to include `{name}` this will show the logger names in the log output, and that should guide you as to how to fine-tune the logging configuration.